# Windows 7 & 8.1 -> Ubuntu 14 - Folder Sharing

Tags: networking, permissions, samba

NOOB LINUX user here...

Recently installed Ubuntu 14 on a Intel NUC.  Everything configured and working.

I have a 4TB EXT USB 3.0 drive that I want to use as my HTPC data drive.

Installed SAMBA and created a couple of shares fro folders located on the external drive.

On my Windows 8.1 desktop I can see the Ubuntu system on the network and the folder shares.  However, when I try to connect I get this:

"Windows cannot access \Ububntu\foldername"
You do not have permission to access \Ubuntu\foldername. Contact your network administrator to request access"

Is there a relatively simple fix for this or will it involve a complicated series of command line edits/commands?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**  verified the exact same thing happens when trying to connect from a Windows 7 system.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/9679184/

**UPDATE 2**

Found this:
http://travelinlibrarian.info/2013/05/how-to-share-an-external-usb-hard-drive-from-ubuntu-to-a-windows-network/

Going to try it after I reinstall UBUNTU & Windows 7 on the NUC.  The UBUNTU install somehow nuked the Windows boot :(

Comment: Sorry, forgot to check back for pastebin. It all looks pretty default and only share seems to be movies. I think the issue is you had browseable = yes commented out.

Comment: Well I give up.  Did fresh install of Ubuntu and now none of my Windows systems can see it.  I can see them from within Ubuntu but not the other way around.  Don;t know if it's a river issue or something else but from what I found searching online Ubuntu/Linux and Windows shares don't play well at all together.

Comment: James, As you're a Linux NOOB, but not a Windows one, did you try shadow accounts?

Comment: Don't give up. Yesterday was bad for me. I'm on my way to work now, but when I get home I will get it setup and write you up another answer. I have done this before on my pi and had no problems with connecting in Windows 8. Did you try to uncomment (take out the ;) on your browseable option on your movie share? I setup the samba share on digital ocean last night over phone, but was too tired to bust out the laptop and try it

Comment: For some reason my dual boot got hosed and I decided to start over.  I ended up getting Ubuntu and then later Fedora, up and running but on both I couldn't even see the LINUX box from any Windows PC (7 or 8.1).I'm not a rookie in the tech world and have been building and working with them for 25 years.  I mean I lived through Netware deployments - I should be able to figure this out :)  Is there a way to test/explore all this without doing an actual hard drive install?Thanks for all your help.

Comment: So I got this working on my pi, which is Debian, but with my digital ocean ubuntu server I wouldn't be able to test out a USB drive. I kept on getting errors until I actually mapped the drive in Windows 8. I had to set it up as //192.168.1.90/geoffmcc and then I was finally given a login prompt. The credentials I setup using the answers provided worked. So in short, set exactly as you had, add the smbpasswd using my answer and then map the drive in Windows. If you try to just //ipaddress it won't give login box.

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: So I was able to finally map a share using your suggestion of the IP + share name from Windows.  However.. When I tried to locate the share from my Amazon Fire TV... nada.  Appreciate all your help but to be honest I can do this under Windows in literally 15 seconds:  Right click - Share - Done.  This started as a challenge but I think I see why LINUX hasn't caught on...

Comment: @James Cygnus Yeah, for sharing to a TV, you want a dnla server, not samba. Check out [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MiniDLNA). When you share with Windows its easy cause windows has a built in dnla since Vista I think (maybe media center edition)

Answer (score 0):

I'm operating on the assumption that your at least getting the login prompt.

There needs to be both an Ubuntu user account and a samba account. Let's say your login in Ubuntu is

> jamesc

You would run

```
 smbpasswd -a jamesc
```

And then go through the prompts to setup the user

Edit: okay, your not getting login prompt and your not sure how to provide us with smb.conf.

Run the following from a terminal

```
 sudo apt-get install pastebinit
```

Once that finishes, still in terminal run

```
 cat /etc/samba/smb.conf | pastebinit
```

And update your question with the link

Update: smb.conf looks pretty default and the only share seems to be movies. I think your issue is you have browseable commented out

```
 ;      browseable = yes
```

when should be

```
 browseable = yes
```

**Edit 2**

So I got it working both on my Raspberry Pi (so I could test USB mount) and I got it working on Ubuntu 14.04.1 on digital ocean, so only could mount home directory there.

All I said in this answer is correct. The password needs setup with

```
sudo smbpasswd -a username
```

The share needs to be browseable.

I too had issues connecting in Windows 8. No login prompt, just gave error (tried to access from search then doing

```
 \\ipaddress
```

But no login and gave error

Then in Windows 8 I went to my computer, map a drive and then (add location also works)

```
 \\192.168.1.90/geoffmcc
```

geoffmcc being the user I setup with smbpasswd .

Works like a charm

Comment: How do I send those credentials from Windows to the Ubuntu system?

Comment: Okay  so windows is not even giving you login prompt as it should.

Comment: No.  Double click on the shard folder name and get that message.

Comment: Can you update your question with a pastebin link of your smb.conf file

Comment: Where would I find that file?  Remember.. LINUX NOOB :)

Comment: See my updated answer